# Using Microdata's 'itemprop' attribute on non-text elements

Tags: html, semantic-markup, schema.org, microdata

I have a following piece of HTML with some Schema.org Microdata added:

```html
<section class="feature" itemprop="description">
    <div class="measure">
      <p>Lorem ipsum etc...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum etc...</p>

      <figure class="polaroid product">
        <img src="dry-aged-beef-horizontal.jpg", alt="Dry Aged Beef", itemprop="image" />
        <figcaption>Dry Aged Beef</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Is it all right to use the `itemprop` attribute on an element that isn't itself a text node (like `section` above), but contains child elements that are?

Looking at the [official Schema.org examples](http://schema.org/Product) one could become suspicious that only text elements can be tagged with Microdata attributes:

```html
<span itemprop="description">0.7 cubic feet countertop microwave.   Has six preset cooking categories and convenience features like   Add-A-Minute and Child Lock.</span>
```

Also, my product description consists of more paragraphs than one, so again setting the `itemprop` tag on a parent element makes all the sense. Is this correct Microdata/Schema.org though?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets ?

Comment: No but I definitely should! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microdata (W3C Note) [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values) that the property value is, in the general case (which applies in your example):

> […] the element's `textContent`.

So yes, your usage is fine.

(Of course this means that "Dry Aged Beef" will also be part of the `description` value.)

Comment: Thanks. When it says "the element's textContent", does it mean that the parser will keep on peeling away that element's child nodes until it finds a text value?

Comment: @user906230: HTML5 references WHATWG’s [DOM Living Standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) where the [definition of `textContent` says](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent): "The concatenation of data of all the Text node descendants of the context object, in tree order." --- So it takes the text of the element and all its descendant elements.