# Does "description" in Schema.org markup have to be free of HTML tags?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

All e-commerce websites with `Product` Schema.org Microdata that I found use plain text in `description` property.

Is there some specification that clearly prohibits markup with some text formatting tags like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Name" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="<p>First paragraph with <b>bold words<b/>.</p><p>Second paragraph.</p>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element). Its [`content` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-content) can only contain a string. If you’d provide a value like `<b>bold</b>`, `<b>` and `</b>` would be part of the value, and these would be interpreted [as text](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68500/17633), not as markup.

For Schema.org’s `description` property, you can of course use a different element (like `p`). This may contain markup, but the value for the `description` property will be [the text value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243802/1591669).

So for

```html
<p itemprop="description">foo <b>bar</b></p>
```

the value would be "foo bar".

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the newer JSON-LD format for schema data then it seems (at least with Google) that it's OK to include HTML markup for some fields - indeed, they actually ask for it. See their recommendation for [JobPostings](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-postings), for example, where they state for description:

> The full description of the job in HTML format.
>
> You must format the description in HTML.

Their [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) certainly doesn't seem to complain about HTML in fields, though you probably want to limit it to basic tags. Whether other parsers are OK with it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of `description` is defined as `Text`. I think it's clear that the intention is that this should be plain text.

In cases where the description ends up on a web page, such as in search engine results, the text will doubtless be HTML-encoded to prevent things like script injection, so will actually be displayed to the user with the angle brackets instead of as formatting.

Answer (score 0):

[Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241605/matthew-strawbridge) is right, you should only provide text as value to `description` meta tag. But [Unor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor) is also right, the recommended method in this case is using microdata to the markup itself, like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
 <p itemprop="name">Product's Name</p>
 <p itemprop="description">Products description.<strong>Some bold text</strong></p>
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) you can see exactly as Google recommends it. And [here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) you can test page by page or even paste your code there to test just a block.

You might want to read [here](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags) why should you avoid using `<b>` for bold.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question. I have a different solution.
The description had tags other than the  tags so it was not read as text by google.

You can pass the description in the content property , like so.

```
  <p itemprop="description" content="<%:Model.Description %>"><%:Html.Raw(Model.Description) %> </p>
```

Perhaps the text should be cleaned before posting it. The tool seems to use it so seems ok to me.